# How to set heading and footnote like pics below for journal?

Tags: footnotes, titles

Please see pictures bemow.
Thanks for your help.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Either the journal provides a class or template file, or you don't need to worry about that, because they do the typesetting themselves. Either way, if you want to mimic that look, use the `authblk` package together with some package for titles like `secsty`.

Comment: @Joseph `sectsty` is not for titles.

Comment: @Johannes_B, you're right. I meant "chapter/section titles" (a.k.a. headings), not "document titles".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=2in]{geometry}


\title{Refund polices for cores with quality variation in OEM remanufacturing}
\author{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}Example Author1 \footnotemark[1]\hspace*{3pt}${}^{,}$\hspace*{3pt}\footnotemark[3]
    \and \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}} Example Author2 \footnotemark[1]\hspace*{3pt}${}^{,}$\hspace*{3pt}\footnotemark[4] 
    \and \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}} Example Author3 \footnotemark[2]\hspace*{3pt}${ }^{,}$\hspace*{3pt}\footnotemark[5]}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\footnotetext[1]{test footnote 1}
\footnotetext[2]{test footnote 2}
\end{minipage}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\footnotetext[3]{test footnote 3 It will be a long footnote with the 3 names and their
email address \href{mailto:exaple3@gmail.com}{example3@gmail.com} and have to take more than one lines including second 
email address etc.}
\footnotetext[4]{test footnote 4}
\footnotetext[5]{test footnote 5}

\end{document}
```

The output is this:
[image: MWE]

Edit:

[image: New image]

And the code for new image here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}



\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
{\huge\bfseries
Refund polices for cores with quality variation in OEM remanufacturing\\\vspace*{20pt}
}

{\large\bfseries
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}Shuoguo Wei\footnotemark[1]\hspace*{1pt}${}^{,}$\hspace*{1pt}\footnotemark[3],\hspace*{15pt}
  Ou Tang\footnotemark[1]\hspace*{1pt}${}^{,}$\hspace*{1pt}\footnotemark[4] ,\hspace*{15pt}
 Weihua Liu\footnotemark[2]\hspace*{1pt}${}^{,}$\hspace*{1pt}\footnotemark[5]
}\vspace*{18pt}

%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\footnotetext[1]{\normalsize Division of Production Economics, Department of Management and Engineering, Linkoping University. SE-581 83 Linkoping, Sweden}
\footnotetext[2]{\normalsize College of Management and Economics, Tianjin University, 300 072, Tianjin, China}

\end{minipage}\hspace*{40pt}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=3cm]{Screenshot1.png}\vspace*{95pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) {\phantom 0};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}\vspace*{46pt}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\footnotetext[3]{\normalsize Corresponding author. Mobile +46 76 4092 743.\\
Email address:\href{mailto:weishuoguo@gmail.com}{weishuoguo@gmail.com} (S. Wei), 
\href{mailto:ou.tang@liu.se}{ou.tang@liu.se} (O. Tang), \href{mailto:weihua.liu@liu.se}{weihua.liu@liu.se}.}
\footnotetext[4]{\normalsize Mobile: +46 13 28 1773}
\footnotetext[5]{\normalsize Visiting scholar at: Division of Production Economics, Department of Management and Engineering,
 Linkoping, University, Sweden. Mobile: +46 13 281767.}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

 \end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```